# logstash-plugin not woking

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash

I have install elasticsearch , kibana and logstash on my server everting work Perfectly but went i want install plugin i have this error message

```
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseParNewGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by jnr.posix.JavaLibCHelper to method sun.nio.ch.SelChImpl.getFD()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of jnr.posix.JavaLibCHelper
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
io/console on JRuby shells out to stty for most operations
LoadError: load error: jopenssl/load -- java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
  require at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
   (root) at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/openssl.rb:1
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
   (root) at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
  require at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
   (root) at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/security.rb:11
   (root) at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
  require at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
   (root) at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/package.rb:43
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
   (root) at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
  require at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
```

went i try to install plugin a write this line

```
sudo -u logstash /urs/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-geoip
```

as in this tuto 
https://www.elastic.co/webinars/getting-started-logstash?baymax=default&elektra=docs&storm=top-video

i aslo try like this

```
sudo ./logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-geoip
```

my java version is 9 and in my `/etc/environment` a have but my java_home variable

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java"
JAVACMD=/usr/bin/java
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

i try to put this variable in my `.bashrc` but is no working 
my server version is ubuntu 16.04

i tyr to change my java version for 8 but nothing change

Comment: Did you have any luck solving this? I'm seeing the same issue trying to run logstash on a mac

Comment: yes the only method a find is remove all java and reinstall just java 8 and after is working. It is necessary to purge all java in your environment file is not is not work